# Spots on leaves

Tags: diagnosis

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is causing the spots on the leaves of this elephant ear plant?  And the discoloring of the stalk?  Soil is moist but not soggy and it gets filtered sunlight on the outdoor patio  in zone 7.

Comment: looks like mealybug or white fly, I can't magnify the photos to see clearly. Check with a magnifying glass...

Comment: Elephant ear can't be too wet, in a riparian location in zone 8 it is invasive.